# Finding corresponding records of a specific value in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
 sales<-c(1,2,3,45,4,3,21)
 price<-c(35,45,30,10,33,44,15)
 df<-data.frame(sales,price)
```

I am looking for way to find the corresponding `price` of the `maximum sales` as well as its `row number` and record them as `a` and `b`.

For instance here maximum `sales` is equal to 45. This is when the `price` is equal to 10 (a should be 10) and this record is on the 4th row (b should be 4).

```
  > a
 [1] 10
 > b
 [1] 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try

```
(x <- df[df$sales == max(df$sales), ])
  sales price
4    45    10
a <- x$price
b <- strtoi(row.names(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- df[which.max(df$sales),][,2]
b <- order(df[,1],decreasing=T)[1]
a
[1] 10
b
[1] 4
```